# c++ class import inside header file

Tags: c++

I have a templated class KeyValue, which defines a key-value pair.

The `class KeyValue` resides in `::distributed::utils` namespace;

Now if I want to use `KeyValue`, I could either write `::distributed::utils::KeyValue my_kv`;

Or for convenience, I could import the namespace:

```
using ::distributed::utils::KeyValue;
```

and then just type `KeyValue my_kv`, whenever I need to use this class.

The problem now I have is that using `::distributed::utils::KeyValue` in a header file
violates the company I work for styleguide (so no "using" allowed in a header file).

Also, I'm writing some templated functions in a header file, and so I can't move them to cc file (any nasty way to do that would also be considered as style-guide violation).

Therefore, the question is:

What would be the good way around it?
One possibility I found is to abbreviate `::distributed::utils` namespace by

```
namespace ::distributed::utils du;
```

And then write `du::KeyValue` wherever I need `KeyValue` object.
But that's still not excellent, as I would need to change `KeyValue` to `distributed::utils::KeyValue` many times (and some other classes as well).

So, any help of how to abbreviate `::distributed::utils::KeyValue` by `KeyValue` inside a header file?

Thanks a lot in advance.

P.s. Changed names to something else not to show companys code.

Comment: You can have `using` "statements" in just about all scopes, and even use it instead of `typedef`. So maybe in the class where you need to use your `KV` type, do e.g. `using KV = ::pipeline::flume::KV;`.

Comment: Your company is right in prohibiting `using` *in the global namespace* of header files.

Comment: I think it is only prohibited to write `using` outside the class definition in the header file, right? So maybe you write your `using` (or `typedef`) statement inside the class, so outside KV is known as `MyTemplateClass::KV` and this should not be a problem or violate anything, imho.

Comment: You are writing a header file, so you must assume that whoever includes your file may have included previously some other files that define some other `KV` in global namespace, for example `int KV;`. And your header file must work nevertheless, so just write `::pipeline::flume::KV` and avoid surprises.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to seek the answer in the code. As it is often stated, code is read more often than written. As a consequence, convenience during typing is a bad reason for a coding/naming choice.

Depending on your environment there are other options. You could use your IDE's expansion settings. For example in NetBeans (I am less experienced with other IDEs but imagine there are equivalent options) you could have `du+<TAB>` expand to `::distributed::utils`, if that is something that you use often. Or you could of course just type `$KV$` and use seek and replace although that would temporarily break code analysis in your IDE.